# Tossing a coin (5,10) and throwing a die (1-6) at the same time twice

Tags: probability, dice

You flip a coin having a 5 on one side and a 10 on the other. At the same time, you throw a normal 6-sided die. So there are 12 possible combinations. You add the two numbers. This gives 10 possible unique results and two possibilities to get 11 (5+6 and 10+1).

If you perform the experiment twice, what is the probability to get 11 at least once?

I thought that this has to be calculated by using the counter-probability. The probability to get 11 is $\frac{2}{12}$ or $\frac{1}{6}$. 
So the counter-probability when doing the experiment twice is $\frac{5}{6}^2  = \frac{25}{36}$. 
Therefore the probability to get 11 at least once should be $\frac{11}{36}$ (30.55 %).

But this seems to be incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the correct answer?  Unless you have mis-stated the question, this seems correct to me.

Comment: I wrote a little simulation in Python and got approx. 44% chance. Despite this, the professor said that the solution is wrong.

Comment: Could you recheck the question. I don't see any way to claim that you are wrong.

Comment: Here is my script:

<!-- language: lang-py -->

import random

def throw():
    '''coin toss'''
    coin = random.choice([5, 10])
    die = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    return bool(coin+die==11)

def main():
    '''perform experiment'''
    t, f = 0, 0 # true , false counter
    for _ in range(1000000):
        throw1 = throw()
        throw2 = throw()
        if throw1 or throw2:
            t+=1
        else:
            f+=1

    print(t/f)

Comment: I hate the fact that I do not know any codes. Can you tell me how I can implement this myself?

Comment: Sorry, I just read that syntax highlighting is not supported in comments.

Comment: No problem. Where can I run this myself?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://repl.it/repls/UnwrittenAwesomeGzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, the probability is $\frac{11}{36}$. Your code (given in comments) is not giving the right answer because it outputs #successes / #failures instead of #successes / #attempts. Just change the last line to `print(t/1000000)`.

Comment: What a stupid bug. Thanks a lot for your answer